# Holes have been drilled in each corner of the board so that it can be fixed to the wall

Tags: grammatical-number

"Holes have been drilled in each corner of the board so that it can be fixed to the wall."

The above sentence is written in my textbook along with a picture showing the board having only one hole in each corner.

The above sentence makes me feel that each corner has two or more holes because the subject "holes" is in plural form.  Is it OK to change the subject "holes" in the above sentence to be in singular form ?

Comment: Or “Holes have been drilled, one in each corner of the board, so that it can be affixed to the wall.”

Comment: You might say "A hole has been drilled in each corner...", but the original is perfectly idiomatic and would be understood by most readers.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would safe to do so, noting that the verb has to change too, ie.

> A hole has been drilled in each corner of the board ...

This is less ambiguous than the original.